# Xml linq. Как обратиться к следующему узлу?

Tags: c#, listview, linq, visual-studio-2017

Структура XML-файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <fio>Карпов</fio>
        <date>10.09.1978</date>
        <home>11 А Победа</home>
        <phone>87509708898</phone>
    </employee>  
    <list_work>
        <work>
            <name>ЖЭК</name>
            <date_start>10.09.2001</date_start>
            <date_end>10.09.2004</date_end>
        </work>
        <work>
            <name>Маркетинг</name>
            <date_start>11.04.2005</date_start>
            <date_end>10.12.2011</date_end>
        </work>
    </list_work>
    <list_pay>
        <pay>
            <year>2004</year>
            <month>09</month>
            <salary>75000</salary>
        </pay>
        <pay>
            <year>2007</year>
            <month>07</month>
            <salary>250000</salary>
        </pay>
    </list_pay>

    <employee>
    <fio>Глухарь</fio>
    <date>02.12.1981</date>
    <home>12 Б Минусинская</home>
    <phone>87509708881</phone>
<list_work>
    <work>
        <name>Рекламный агент</name>
        <date_start>10.03.2011</date_start>
        <date_end>05.09.2014</date_end>
    </work>
    <work>
        <name>F1</name>
        <date_start>11.04.2016</date_start>
        <date_end>08.10.2018</date_end>
    </work>
</list_work>
<list_pay>
    <pay>
        <year>2012</year>
        <month>06</month>
        <salary>56000</salary>
    </pay>
    <pay>
        <year>2015</year>
        <month>12</month>
        <salary>550000</salary>
    </pay>
</list_pay>
</employee> 
</employees>
```

Мне нужно выбрать фамилию, адрес и название работы и загрузить эту информацию в listView.

```
xDoc = XDocument.Load("worker.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> workers = xDoc.Elements();

            foreach (XElement worker in workers.Elements())
            {

                listView1.Items.Add(worker.Element("fio").Value);
                listView1.Items[worker.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(worker.Element("home").Value);
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(worker.Element("name").Value);
            }
```

Но когда я запускаю программу, выводится только фамилия и адрес и то только первая запись, а название работы вовсе нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы выводил все записи, то есть фамилию и адрес, а также, чтоб выводил название работы ?

Comment: Во-первых, исправьте xml. Во-вторых, для отображения табличных данных используйте `DataGridView` вместо `ListView`. В-третьих, используйте привязку данных (binding): вместе с гридом это просто и удобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml невалидный.
 В одном случае узел list_work это самостоятельный узел,
в другом — list_work вложен в узел employee. 
На случай, если в документе узел list_work вложенный:

```
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("worker.xml");
    foreach (var employee in xelement.Elements())
    {
        string[] arr = new string[3]
        {
          employee.Element("fio").Value,
          employee.Element("home").Value,
          ""
        };

        var works = employee.Element("list_work").Elements("work")
            .Select(work => work.Element("name").Value).ToList();

        if (works.Count > 0)
            arr[2] = works[0];

        listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(arr));

        foreach (var item in works.Skip(1))
        {
            arr = new string[3] { "", "", item };
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(arr));
        }
    }
```